# Xamarin Not Run the Emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

developers I am new in Xamarin I am just Install the Visual Studio 2017 and start vs and select Cross-platform app and then select these options refer to image 1
[image: This is Image 1]

then It through this warning I am attached the notepad screenshot with it

[image: This is 2nd image]

and when I follow this instruction then it through this warning

[image: 3rd Image]

Comment: so what was in the log file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ObjectModel Warning Xamarin does not run on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270342/system-objectmodel-warning-xamarin-does-not-run-on-android)

Comment: I am try this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270342/system-objectmodel-warning-xamarin-does-not-run-on-android


but i not found mono android folder in my pc